# What is the difference between MotionLayout and Animation in Android & which one should we use?

Tags: android-motionlayout

MotionLayout Extends ConstraintLayout and have all its feature while we can move a widget on click in Motionlaout scene and we can also move a widget via our old Animation. I just want to ask which one is better and which one to use and what is the difference.